# Edit text - input type

Tags: android

[image]How to validate in edit text that the input should accept only numbers and(. and /). I tried giving number signed, but it not allow me to enter /. Is there any way to allow /? . Please looking forward for the response.

I tried:

```
android:inputType="number|numberSigned"
```

Comment: Post the code you tried so far.

Comment: android:inputType="number|numberSigned"

Comment: ur checking tjis in emulator or real device?

Answer (score 1):

**Have you tried:**

```
android:digits="0123456789./"
```

Comment: Yes..tried. if i give inputType="number" or "number|numberSigned" or "number|numberdecimal" and digits="0123456789./", I couldn't able to get / in keypad itself. It's in hidden state.

Comment: dont use `inputType="number" or "number|numberSigned" or "number|numberdecimal"` just use the `digits` and may be `inputType="number|text"`

Comment: Used digits and inputType="number|text". got response only number is viewing in keypad..(. and / not shown)

Comment: Yes. Removed input type and tried using digits="0123456789./". But . and / aren't showing in keypad

Comment: Hey can you post the screenshot. Because it doesn't appear on the 1st screen, but appears only when you switch to numbers.

Comment: Have uploaded the screenshot. Please refer it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use InputFilter, but remember that it'll override your current filter.

```
public static InputFilter getLetterFilter() {
    InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                                   Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                if (source.charAt(i) != '/' && !Character.isLetter(source.charAt(i))) {
                    return "";
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    return filter;
}
```

And add this filter to edittext

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{getLetterFilter()});
```

Answer (score 0):

You use

```
android:digits="0123456789./"
```

for `EditText` in xml and do not use `inputType`